# Maven: copy an artifact with its all dependencies from local repository to another directory

Tags: android, maven, dependencies, repository, artifact

I have this artifact https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.build/gradle/3.4.0-alpha07 and its all dependencies in my local repository (.m2/repository).
Now how to copy this artifact with its all dependencies to specific folder?

---

dependency:copy-dependencies just copied jar files.
i want to copy an artifact with its all dependencies like the structure of a local repository folder.

**Any idea how to do this?**

Comment: @KashifRafique It's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

I would create a dummy project which has the named dependency as only dependency. Then you can do `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` to copy all (transitive) dependencies to a specific folder.

Comment: dependency:copy-dependencies just copied jar files. i want to copy an artifact with its all dependencies like the structure of a local repository folder.

Comment: if you write a pom.xml with your artifact as dependency, `dependency:copy-dependencies` will copy all transitive dependencies of that artifact to the desired folder. Do you want something different?